# Process.spawn_sync error

Tags: runtime-error, vala, spawn

I found the following strange behaviour of Process.spawn_sync in Vala:

If I do in command line:
`valac -C *.vala`
It outputs c code and everything is fine.

If I do it programmatically:

```cs
string sStdOut, sStdErr, sDir = "."; int nErr;

string sCmd = "valac -C *.vala";

string argv;
bool ok = Shell.parse( sCmd, argv );
if (ok) {
  ok = Process.spawn_sync(
         sDir,
         argv,
         Environ.get(),
         SpawnFlags.SEARCH_PATH,
         null,
         out sStdOut,
         out sStdErr,
         out nErr
       );

  if (!ok) {
    stderr.printf("%s", sStdErr);
  }

}
```

It outputs:
`error: *.vala not found`

This confuses me! Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you're getting Shell.parse, but [GLib.Shell.parse_argv](http://valadoc.org/glib-2.0/GLib.Shell.parse_argv.html)

> "Parses a command line into an argument vector, in much the same way the shell would, but without many of the expansions the shell would perform (variable expansion, **[globs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29)**, operators, filename expansion, etc. are not supported)."

You could iterate through the directory and match them manually (using [GLib.PatternSpec](http://valadoc.org/glib-2.0/GLib.PatternSpec.html) if you want to maintain the glob-style syntax), or you could (ab)use bash by using something like `bash -c 'valac -C *.vala'` instead of directly invoking valac.

Comment: What I didn't know is, that the shell is usually handling those things and not the app itself. Learned that now ;-) Wrote my own parser now.

Comment: That seems unwise.  GLib.PatternSpec seems like *exactly* what you want, and its well-tested code which is likely less buggy than your code (no offense, just the whole "given enough eyeballs, all bugs are shallow" thing).  You're already using glib, so there isn't really a reason not to use it...